# Creating a completely custom UIRefreshControl

Tags: ios, objective-c, uirefreshcontrol

I need to create an entirely custom `UIRefresh` control. Animation, image, pull down amount, etc...

My initial thought is to start from scratch, use a UIViewController, add my own view to it, animate by accessing the `UIScrollViewDelegate` methods.

I can do all this but is there a way with slightly less work and easier to add to multiple `UITableView`s?

Is it possible to subclass `UIRefreshControl` and change this amount of stuff inside it?

Answer (score 3):

**ANSWER UPDATED**

- [GitHub](https://github.com/backslash-f/quartzcode-uirefreshcontrol) project update to Swift 3.1
- Updated QuartzCode to version
  1.55.0 (changes on the generated code)
- Code refactored to use the new `refreshControl` property [(introduced in iOS
  10)](https://useyourloaf.com/blog/refresh-control-changes-in-ios-10/) (also more "swifty" now).
- Included @Hanny's suggestion (down below) (thanks!)

---

I like the YouTube link you posted. :) Nice result.

For reference: QuartzCode is pretty good for creating a `UIRefreshControl` animation from scratch.

Check out [this little project](https://github.com/backslash-f/quartzcode-uirefreshcontrol) (GitHub).
In it, you will find the QuartzCode project file as well as an example on how to integrate it with a `UITableView`.

I think the most important part in there is the `refresh` function:

```
/// Called everytime refresh control's value changes.
///
/// - parameter sender: The `UIRefreshControl` of this TableView.
@IBAction func refresh(_ sender: UIRefreshControl) {

    animate()

    // In this "demo", the refresh will last 5.0 seconds.
    DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 5) {

        // Do something with the retrieved data...
        // TODO

        // ... then end the refresh operation.
        self.refreshControl?.endRefreshing()

        // Stop animations.
        self.stopAnimations()
    }
}
```

Look how easy is to use the animations:

```
/// Three examples. Uncomment / comment to check all of them.
func animate() {

    // Example 01.
    animateCloudUpAndDown()

    // Example 02.
    //animateCloudStrokeWithGradientFill()

    // Example 03.
    //animateCloudStrokeWithSolidFill()
}

// MARK: - Animation Examples

/// Animates the cloud up and down.
func animateCloudUpAndDown() {
    customUIRefreshControl.addRefreshUpDownAnimation()
}

/// "Draws" the cloud by make its stroke line gradually visible, then shows
/// a solid blueish background and then fades everything out.
func animateCloudStrokeWithGradientFill() {
    customUIRefreshControl.addRefreshGradientAnimation()
}

/// "Draws" the cloud by make its stroke line gradually visible, then shows
/// a gradient blueish background and then fades everything out.
func animateCloudStrokeWithSolidFill() {
    customUIRefreshControl.addRefreshSolidAnimation()
}
```

Cheers!

Comment: I think animate() would be better placed at the beginning of the refresh function. No point in animating while we're scrolling through out data.

Comment: @Hanny, thanks a lot for your comment. I agree. I made some changes to the code and included your suggestion. Take a look. ;)

Answer (score 1):

`EGOTableViewPullRefresh` is awesome "pull down to refresh" feature. It is available on [github](https://github.com/enormego/EGOTableViewPullRefresh). You can customize your pics, behavior, etc.
`UIRefreshControl` is available only in iOS 6.0 and later. `EGOTableViewPullRefresh` can be used in iOS 5 and earlier!

Comment: Thanks, looks similar to how I was going to do it myself :)

Answer (score 0):

we have a tutorial with sample code in Objective-C and Swift for implementing Custom Pull to Refresh controls.  You can find it here: http://www.jackrabbitmobile.com/design/ios-custom-pull-to-refresh-control/

Hope it helps and let me know if you have any questions!

--Anthony

Comment: Thanks, I was able to get it working in the end. http://youtu.be/lN1HejGmlYI very little code as it was all about getting the layout constraints right.